# toggle over tabs in terminal with mouse wheel in 20.04

Tags: mouse, gnome-terminal, 20.04, tabs, mouse-wheel

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and I am unable to toggle between the tabs in the terminal with the mouse wheel, which was fine in 18.04. I can't find where this feature is enabled. Is it possible that this feature has been removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality was removed by GNOME developers.
I can confirm this issue and reported it already against 19.04, 19.10 and 20.04 LTS as [bug 1807603](https://pad.lv/1807603) to launchpad.

Possible alternative - use MATE Terminal (`sudo apt-get install mate-terminal`) or switch to the MATE DE completely by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^` as we can't predict what else is broken in the newest GNOME Shell.

Comment: Thanks a lot, MATE Terminal installed and working fine. I am becoming more annoyed with each new version of Ubuntu, they keep changing things that were fine already... I hope they will bring back the scrolling at some point.

Comment: The real source of annoyance is GNOME Shell new-wave open-minded developings. The Ubuntu chose wrong default desktop as we see :)

Comment: Yes, and I add that I hate the Yaru new theme and to my dismay it seems that I can not go back to Ambiance, or at least it does appear in the Tweaks menu and I don't find where can I download it...